# Finding the difference in value counts by keys in two Dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have two sample python dictionaries that counts how many times each key appears in a DataFrame.

```
dict1 =  {
           2000 : 2,
           3000 : 3,
           4000 : 4,
           5000 : 6,
           6000 : 8
          }
```

```
dict2 = {
           4000 : 4,
           3000 : 3,
           2000 : 4,
           6000 : 10,
           5000 : 4
          }
```

I would like to output the following where there is a difference.

```
diff = {
        2000 : 2
        5000 : 2
        6000 : 2
       }
```

I would appreciate any help as I am not familiar with iterating though dictionaries. Even if the output shows me at which key there is a difference in values, it would work for me. I did the following but it does not produce any output.

```
for (k,v), (k2,v2) in zip(dict1.items(), dict2.items()):
    if k == k2:
        if v == v2:
            pass
        else:
            print('value is different at k')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you're doing doesn't work because the dicts are not sorted, so `k==k2` is always evaluated False.

You could use a dict comprehension where you traverse `dict1` and subtract the value in `dict2` with the matching key:

```
diff = {k: abs(v - dict2[k]) for k, v in dict1.items()}
```

Output:

```
{2000: 2, 3000: 0, 4000: 0, 5000: 2, 6000: 2}
```

If you have Python >=3.8, and you want only key-value pairs where value > 0, then you could also use the walrus operator:

```
diff = {k: di for k, v in dict1.items() if (di := abs(v - dict2[k])) > 0}
```

Output:

```
{2000: 2, 5000: 2, 6000: 2}
```

Since you tagged it as `pandas`, you can also do a similar job in pandas as well.

First, we need to convert the dicts to DataFrame objects, then `join` them. Since `join` joins by index by default and the indexes are the keys in the dicts, you get a nice DataFrame where you can directly find the difference row-wise. Then use the `diff` method on axis + `abs` to find the differences.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict1, orient='index')
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict2, orient='index')
out = df1.join(df2, lsuffix='_x', rsuffix='').diff(axis=1).abs().dropna(axis=1)['0']
```

Also, instead of creating two DataFrames and `join`ing them, we could also build a single DataFrame by passing a list of the dicts, and use similar methods to get the desired outcome:

```
out = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([dict1, dict2]).diff().dropna().abs().loc[1]
```

Output:

```
2000    2
3000    0
4000    0
5000    2
6000    2
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're counting... how about using [`Counter`s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)?

```
c1, c2 = Counter(dict2), Counter(dict1)
diff = dict((c1-c2) + (c2-c1))
```

If you used `Counter`s all around, you wouldn't need the conversions from `dict` and back. And maybe it would also simplify the creation of your two count dicts (Can't tell for sure since you didn't show how you created them).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZDLCoMwEEX3@YpZJlQhDytS6KqfMlUa0CSkcVGk355qI9RAoLObw2XOZdwrPKxRnfMxDt5OgHYcewzamifoyVkf4GZnE3pPyF1jEHAFWAj8RnLO4QKyOkKVoMpgk2CTwXOCbQbbBLsDeye/XP3L36NFvSwld5PgpVJN7kdRAW4F9o/QbyFWZbtga89hWFPbRimKGiWDE1CUNQrGCHFem0C3FIvxAw)